# elasticsearch fill gaps with previous value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have time series data in Elasticsearch and I want to aggregate it to create histogram. What I want to achieve is to fill the null buckets with the value of the previous data point. I know that I can use `min_doc_count: 0` but it will put the value as 0 and I couldn't find any out of the box way to do this via Elastic. May be there is some trick that I am not aware of?
Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Date Histogram Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) does not provide a native way to perform what you would like.

The closest thing I can think of is using [missing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html). However, this will set a static value to all the dates where no values are found, which is not exactly what you want.

I also thought of using [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-walkthrough.html) with the following logic:

1. Get the first value in the Histogram and store it in a variable `current`.
2. If the next value is different to 0, store this value to `current`.
3. If the value is 0, set the `current` value to the histogram date. Don't change `current`.
4. Repeat step 2 until you finish the Histogram.

Using painless, in my experience is really painful but you can consider it as an alternative.

Additionally, I would recommend you to limit ES to perform searches and aggregations. If you require additional logic to the output, consider performing it outside ES. You can use the [Python ES Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for instance.

I can think of the following script with a similar logic as the Painless scenario:

```
current = 0
results = es.search(...)
for i in res["aggregations"]["my_histogram_name"]["buckets"]:
    if not i["doc_count"]: #this is the same as "if i["doc_count"]==0"
        i["doc_count"] = current
    current = i["doc_count"] #changed or not, we always use the last value to current
```

After that, the histogram should look as you want and ready to be displayed.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: thanks Kevin for the reply. Missing value feature is not for my use case. The further processing in the application side to fill the gaps is something I am doing already. Wanted to see if there is any native way in elasticsearch I can achieve the same.

Comment: "Using painless, in my experience is really painful" 